# Google Maps api v2 getFromLocationName() returns no results for valid address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Using Google maps website I can find the address, but when I use my app to find a specific address using getFromLocationName I get no results. I can find the addresses around the one I am searching for but not the one I need.
(searching for city hall)ex

getFromLocationName(123 test) = no results

getFromLocationName(121 test) = 121 Test St, Test City, 11111, NA

getFromLocationName(122 test) = 122 Test St, Test City, 11111, NA

getFromLocationName(124 test) = 124 Test St, Test City, 11111, NA

getFromLocationName(125 test) = 125 Test St, Test City, 11111, NA

getFromLocationName(city hall) = City Hall 123 Test St, Test City, 11111, NA

getFromLocation(city hall lat, city hall lng) = 123 Test St, Test City, 11111, NA

Why would the search return the correct results for every address around the city hall and the city hall's address itself when using the name or coordinates? Does anyone know of a good workaround for such an situation? Is it possible to run a search online in the background to get results in a JSON object if the original search results are empty?